# Are mysql connections closed automatically in NodeJS?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I've been working with Express and the  [mysql package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), this pacakge provides a connection.destroy() method, but I've been working on a project without ever using it once.

I did a stress test using [siege](https://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) and the server never responded in a wrong way through out the test.

All I want to know, is the connection closed automatically or is it kept open?

**Note :** I normally require a module that will return the connection at the start of every route script and just use the connection through out the script without ever destroying it. Is this dangerous later on in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't call `end` or `destroy` on the connection then it will stay alive until your application is exited or if the connection is closed by the mysql server due to inactivity. So yes you should always call `end` on the connection if you don't use it anymore so that I will be returned to the pool (if you use one) or is closed.

Comment: What about concurrent requests will it affect my server's behavior if let's say /bar and /foo got requests at the same time, knowing that both of them will require a connection object from a module I created?

Comment: @Oussama Not sure what you want to know. Normally you will create an individual connection for each request and close the corresponding connection when you gathered all information you need to create the response. But what do you mean with `will it affect my server's behavior if let's say /bar and /foo got requests at the same time` what do you think might happen then or might be the problem there?

Comment: You already answered my question, I just had a misunderstanding of the whole concept; I thought all the request shared the same connection and thought some kind of conflict may occur. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Oussama Until you have a better understanding how server-side javascript and async code works, you should use an own connection for each request. So if you have multiple concurrent connection each requesting `/bar` all of them would have a separate connection. This is for sure not the best solution, it would be better to have some caching layer in between, because if you already gather the information for `/bar` and another request arrives also requesting `/bar` then you most likely don't want to start a new connection to request the same data, but send the result to both requests.

Comment: Is that where the usage of pools comes in handy?

Comment: @Oussama This is more a new question, I can't answer you all questions in the comment section. ... When creating new connection the library first needs to establish the connection to mysql, doing a handshake and authentication, this will take some time, if you have a less frequent page this is not a problem and a pool would not have a benefit. But if the number of requests increase then it would be a vast of cpu power to close and open connection in a high frequency. A pool will not immediately close a connection, but allow you to reuse still open connections that are not used anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much. And sorry I asked too much questions. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Oussama the problem is not that you ask :D. SO only works well because people answer voluntary questions in their spare time or because companies allow there workers to answer while they work. So it is important the question and answers ideally would help more then one person. Therefore the question has to be  well written, and that you only ask one question per question. So if you have a follow up question, open a new one and reference previous question in the new one.